# $3$rd order ODE with constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm confused with the procedure on how to solve this problem.

> Find a basis for the space of solutions for the differential equation:
>   $$y''' − 3y'' + 3y'− y = 0.$$

Comment: What do you mean by "Verify that $y=-x$"? It does not seem to fit with the rest of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution 
$$y'''−3y''+3y'−y=0.\\ { \lambda  }^{ 3 }-3{ \lambda  }^{ 2 }+3\lambda -1=0\\ { \left( \lambda -1 \right)  }^{ 3 }=0\\ { \lambda  }_{ 1,2,3 }=1$$

> $$\\ y={ e }^{ x }\left( { C }_{ 1 }+{ C }_{ 2 }x+{ C }_{ 3 }{ x }^{ 2 } \right) \\ \\ $$

Comment: Thanks but how did you realize (x-1)^3 was the non expanded form of the line before it?

Comment: sorry but i couldn't catch what you mean

Comment: @user353452 That is the "cube rule" backwards, $$(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3,$$ with $a=\lambda$ and $b=-1$. If you do not recognize it (then you should learn to!) you might perhaps guess a root and then do polynomial long division.

Comment: Thank you, I know polynomial division but I thought it would be ridiculous if they made us memorize that much.

Comment: @user353452 Note that this is a special case of the binomial theorem, which is very useful indeed...

Comment: Oh okay, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$y'''(x)-3y''(x)+3y'(x)−y(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Assume a solution will be proportional to $e^{\mu x}$ for some constannt $\mu$.

Substitute $y(x)=e^{\mu x}$:

---

$$\frac{\text{d}^3}{\text{d}x^3}\left(e^{\mu x}\right)-3\cdot\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}x^2}\left(e^{\mu x}\right)+3\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(e^{\mu x}\right)−e^{\mu x}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Subsitute:

- $$\frac{\text{d}^3}{\text{d}x^3}\left(e^{\mu x}\right)=\mu^3e^{\mu x}$$
- $$\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}x^2}\left(e^{\mu x}\right)=\mu^2e^{\mu x}$$
- $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(e^{\mu x}\right)=\mu e^{\mu x}$$

  ---

$$\mu^3e^{\mu x}-3\mu^2e^{\mu x}+3\mu e^{\mu x}−e^{\mu x}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{\mu x}\left(\mu^3-3\mu^2+3\mu−1\right)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Since $e^{\mu x}\ne0$ for a finite $\mu$, zeros must come from the polynomial:

---

$$\mu^3-3\mu^2+3\mu−1=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(\mu-1)^3=0$$

So, for $\mu$ we get three times the solution $1$.

Now, we get the general solution:

$$y(x)=\text{C}_1e^x+\text{C}_2xe^x+\text{C}_3x^2e^x$$